# Moving array overrides values

Tags: java, arrays

My array is filled in the beginning with a string. Then the user can enter a new string. I want my array to shift to the right, like `{a,x,x,x}` should move the a to the right `{x,a,x,x}` so new entries can move up. When I run my code it puts the entered string in the first position of the array, but in the next step it doesn't move the entered string, but prints out an array only filled with the predefined string. Why doesn't it contain my entered string?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        int i;
        String n = new String("n");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;

        String affe [] = new String [5];
        Arrays.fill(affe, n);

        a = sc.next();

        affe[0] = a;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(affe));

        for(i = 0; i<affe.length-1; i++){
            affe[i] = affe[i+1];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(affe));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(affe), 1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't I get a mismatch because affe is a string array and i and integer?

Comment: @JoeS sorry, amended.

Comment: The code works, but it puts the entered string to the last position. It should just be moved one position to the right

Comment: @JoeS remove loop then.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how I delete the last element then, so I don't get out of bounds?

Comment: Why would I remove the loop? It should not just move the String, but the complete array content to the right

Comment: @JoeS I understood what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You're copying the wrong way around.

Change this line:

```
affe[i] = affe[i+1];
```

to

```
affe[i+1] = affe[i];
```

But you also need to change the order of the loop to go from back to front. Otherwise, each subsequent iteration brings the one value from the start forward to the end. So change the loop to:

```
for (int i = affe.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    affe[i+1] = affe[i];
}
```

Comment: I tried it, like this the array is filled with the entered string completely

Comment: @JoeS I've added how you need to change the order of the loop.